# Filtering a table using 2 different text-boxe code in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that filters a table when a word typed in the text-box. It works fine for 1 word but what I need is to make to filter with 2 words.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Worksheets("Prices").ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & [B3] & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried making another text-box with same code and typed two different words in them but then it filtered the table for either of the words I typed. That is not what I want. The filtered results must contain both of the words that typed, not either of them. Can you help me improve this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameters "Operator" and "Cirteria2" in your Autofilter functions.

You have to refer to the second TextBox in your code for your first TextBox and vice versa.

For example:

```
Worksheets("Prices").ListObjects("Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & [B3] & "*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="*" & [B4] & "*"
```

... if your second Textbox is in B4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend. This is exactly what I wanted to do.